# Static reference to a <div> tag in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am still quite new to jQuery and I am trying to setup the jQuery.Validate plugin so that it displays all of the error messages below the submit button instead of all over in the document. I have a table of options with a check box on each row. The no check box selected error message shows on the first row of the table which will cause confusion for the users.

Is there a way to define a "static path" to a  tag so that it can always be found? Or what am I doing wrong?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
        $("#form1").validate({
            rules: {
                "CbSelect[]": {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 1
                }
            },
            messages: {
                "CbSelect[]": {
                    required: "Please select at least one employee.",
                    minlength: "Please select at least one employee."
                }
            },
            errorContainer: "#errorList",
            errorLabelContainer: "#errorList ul",
            wrapper: "li",
            debug: true
        });
```

Here is my code with only the relevant parts:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Display", "Supervisor", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "form1" }))
   { %>
<%= Html.DropDownList("DropDownAction", new SelectList(Model.Actions, "Value", "Text"), "(Select)", new { Class = "required" })%>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<div class="errorList">
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>
<fieldset>
    <table id="employees">
        <tr id="rowHeader">
            <th style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkall" />
            </th>
            ...
        </tr>
        <% foreach (var item in Model.Timesheets)
           { %>
        <tr id="<%= Html.Encode(item.Id) %>">
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="checkbox" name="CbSelect[]" class="selected" value="<%= Html.Encode(item.Id) %>" />
            </td>
            ...
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
</fieldset>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops... I figured it out. I have `<div class="errorList">` I use `"#errorList"` when it should be `".errorList"`

Thanks to all who looked at this.

Comment: I have to wait 2 days before I can do that... a bit annoying.